# Can't build or archive app using xcodebuild "...-frameworks.sh: line 42: source: unbound variable"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, xcodebuild

I am unable to build our app using the xcodebuild command, however if I open the project in xcode and click build or archive from the Product menu, it builds absolutely fine. I can't work out what I am doing differently via cli that is causing it to error.

The command I am using:

`xcodebuild archive -scheme Dropless -configuration Release -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES`

The error:

`/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Dropless/Pods-Dropless-frameworks.sh: line 42: source: unbound variable Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`

I have seen various posts online about this error and all seem to point toward the same thing with the defined architectures, however nothing I do seems to make a difference and if it builds in xcode manually I can't see there being an issue with what I've defined.
This is my settings:
[image: Defined Architectures]

- xcode version: 13.4.1
- osx version: 12.5.1 Monterey

Comment: any update? i have the same error and all the answers regarding excluding arm64 are not working.

Comment: @m_wer sadly not, both in the same boat I think

Comment: i was able to resolve it. It was an issue with my podfile. I had still occurances of 'pod <podXY>' due to a 3rd party library in it. After removing it, the error was resolved. (I replaced the library with another one). I also found another answer which also stated the error was caused by the podfile. So check your podfile closely, hopefully you will be able to resolve it!